# React Native Swift UI Component frame size

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am developing native ui components in swift to add to my react native mobile app.  I have a root view that gets created by the manager class which inherits from RCTManager.  Inside that view I am using autolayout to determine the size and positions of subviews.  However, some of the nested subviews actually need to know their parent view’s frame size (width & height).  The problem is that I need these values when the init method is called on the root view, but by using autolayout it seems it is not possible to get those values.  With a react native app it appears that a lot of the logic that would normally be in a view controller for a pure ios app is now in the actual view.  So, methods such as viewDidLayoutSubviews are not accessible within the view manager or the view.  I would really appreciate any guidance or help regarding this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If understand your question correctly, the way I solved this problem was utilizing [`UIView.layoutSubview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews). Within that method, you should have access to the parent `UIView`'s frame/bounds, which you could use to calculate the frame for your attached child views.

```
class MyView : UIView {
    var label:UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        label = UILabel()
        label?.text = "Hello World!"
        label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.addSubview(label!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        label?.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```